# fetch data from one table and post it in another

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables called (members & families). I want to get family_ID from families table and post it on members table using cakephp3. How can I do that?

I also have parent and spouse fields in my members table. I want to fetch particular member_ID for both.

I think my query would be:

```
$parentID = SELECT member_id 
            FROM members
            WHERE member.fname = "",  member.mname = "", member.lname = "", member.family_id = "";
```

Then post the result in the field parentID.

Is it correct?

Comment: Provide tables fields list, and what do you mean by "post it"?

Comment: membersTable 'id', 'fname','mname,'lname','family_id','age','sex','dob','adress'.

Comment: family table:  'family_id','state','country'.                                                                               I want the family_id to be on the drop down list in members table to select.

Answer (score 0):

As per http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs you can do following in your controller

```
$members = $this->Members->find('list')
    ->matching('Spouse', function ($query) { return $query->where([]); }

$this->set(compact('members'));
```

and then use the following inside your form:

```
echo $this->Form->input('member_id');
```

This would automatically fetch the variable and use that as the list - as per: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data

I'd also read http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations on "saving with associations"